# Visual Studio XSD Tool Error?

Tags: .net, xsd

I have XSD as below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="Test"
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Test.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Test.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/Test.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
    <xs:complexType name="TestCurrency">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="CurrencyRef"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="CurrentRefSpecified"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="Currency" type="TestCurrency"/>

</xs:schema>
```

When I ran the XSD Tool with below command in VS 2008 command prompt:
xsd /classes /language:vb test.xsd

I get below code

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' <auto-generated>
'     This code was generated by a tool.
'     Runtime Version:2.0.50727.3615
'
'     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
'     the code is regenerated.
' </auto-generated>
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Xml.Serialization

'
'This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=2.0.50727.3038.
'

'''<remarks/>
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038"),  _
 System.SerializableAttribute(),  _
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),  _
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),  _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute([Namespace]:="http://tempuri.org/Test.xsd"),  _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("Currency", [Namespace]:="http://tempuri.org/Test.xsd", IsNullable:=false)>  _
Partial Public Class TestCurrency

    Private currencyRefField As Integer

    Private currentRefSpecified1Field As Integer

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property CurrencyRef() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me.currencyRefField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.currencyRefField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("CurrentRefSpecified")>  _
    Public Property CurrentRefSpecified1() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me.currentRefSpecified1Field
        End Get
        Set
            Me.currentRefSpecified1Field = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

When the element I have specified is CurrentRefSpecified. Why it is showing as CurrentRefSpecified1 in the generated class? Is it issue with XSD or my issue?

Can anyone quickly answer this?

This appending is automatically happening when we have element name say 'xyzspecified'.. the property in the class file is set as xyzspecified1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know for sure, but here's my assumption: for certain fields in the XML, if they could be left out or specified, `xsd.exe` will generate a corresponding field called `(yourfieldname)Specified` to signal whether or not a potentially nillable/missing value has actually been specified.

Now this is not the case in your sample anywhere as it is now - but if you would change your XSD to make your field `CurrentRef` be nillable or have `minOccurs=0` on it, then the xsd.exe tool would have to create a `CurrentRefSpecified` helper field for it, and this would clash with your already existing field in the XSD.

I am guessing that the xsd tool will "rename" your field  `CurrentRefSpecified` to `CurrentRefSpecified1`, in order to avoid any potential (future) clash.